# How to use multithreading here

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a code in which a large chunk of data is queried. The problem is the autogenerated query is becoming too large and usually timeouts so i decided to divide the data in my code only in order to make the code work and not give timeout exception. Also, I decided to use multi-threading creating 100 threads.
Below is my piece of code

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100);
        final int size=nodeIds.size()%100==0?(nodeIds.size()/100):(nodeIds.size()/100)+1;
        List<Future<CacheImpl<BacktestingResult>>> futures = new ArrayList<Future<CacheImpl<BacktestingResult>>>(100);
        for(int i=0;i<nodeIds.size();){
            final int start=i;
            futures.add(executor.submit(new Callable<CacheImpl<BacktestingResult>>() {      
                public CacheImpl<BacktestingResult> call() {
                    return new CacheImpl<BacktestingResult>(
                            ServiceLocator.getBalanceService().getBacktestingResults(
                                    report.getCriteria().fromDate,
                                    report.getCriteria().toDate,
                                    new ArrayList<String>(new ArrayList<String>(nodeIds).subList(start, size+start)),
                                    report.getCriteria().getExceptionCategories(),
                                    report.getCriteria().getExceptionTypes(),
                                    report.getCriteria().getGroup().getCriteria()));
                }
            }));
            i=i+size+1;
        }
```

The problem is it is still not working and probably creation of 100 threads is not ideal. Can somebody suggest a better way to do this. The nodeIds coming here are >200000 .

Comment: You have omitted most of the information needed to answer the question: The query text; the code that invokes the query, the table definitions involved, the EXPLAIN PLAN output.  Please help us to help you.

Comment: Usually, as far as I remember, having more threads than virtual cores doesn't add much up. If you have a QuadCore with 8 virtual cores, the (usually) optimal number of threads would be 8, so you can split them across all cores.
(Of course this mostly applies to calculating data. If you're using the network, it's whole another story.

Comment: I think you should try with fixed size chunk eg chunks of 100 `nodeId`s and in `for` loop, you should use condition `i < size`. Then use `subList(start, size*(start+1))` to get sub list.